# How can I check recent hive account transactions in JavaScript i

Tags: javascript, hive, blockchain

I really want to check recent account transactions on hive-engine

Could you please help me with a JavaScript way of checking recent account transactions

I really want to check recent account transactions on hive-engine

Could you please help me with a JavaScript way of checking recent account transactions

const hive = require(‘@hiveio-hivejs’)

hive.getAccountHistory(………………//but it doesn’t give me what I want

Answer (score 1):

To check recent Hive account transactions using JavaScript, you can utilize the Hive blockchain's APIs. Here's an example of how you can retrieve recent transactions for a specific account:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getRecentTransactions(account) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.hive.blog/api/transactions/history/${account}`);
    const transactions = response.data;
    
    // Process and handle the transactions as per your requirements
    console.log(transactions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving account transactions:', error);
  }
}

// Replace 'your_account_name' with the desired Hive account name
getRecentTransactions('your_account_name');
```

In the code snippet above, we are using the Axios library to make a GET request to the Hive blockchain API endpoint ([https://api.hive.blog/api/transactions/history/{account}](https://api.hive.blog/api/transactions/history/%7Baccount%7D)), where {account} is the Hive account name you want to retrieve transactions for.

Once you receive the response, you can process and handle the transactions as needed. In the example, we simply log the transactions to the console, but you can perform any further operations or data manipulation as required for your specific use case.

Make sure you have the axios library installed (`npm install axios`) before running this code.

Note: The example uses the Hive blockchain's api.hive.blog endpoint, but you can also explore other Hive API endpoints or libraries that provide more specific functionalities if needed.